# 8 pin automotive connector identification

Tags: connector

[image: M/F 8 pin connector]

I am trying to identify this M/F connector combination. (only three of the bottom row are used) It is a Volvo connector, connecting the steering column lock to the wire harness. The male plug is ~16mm x 7.6mm. I'm trying to build a short jumper cable, but I can't find this particular plug anywhere. It is stamped on the back AMP but TE (who bought AMP) was little help. I don't need the full 8 pins; a row if 4 pins would work fine. Gerry-rig is fine. I am trying to reposition the Volvo SCL so it can't stand us anymore!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A keyless header ought to fit if you can measure the pin size and pitch (0.1" or 3mm? Pitch)

Comment: A few thoughts: 1. Ask the parts department at your local Volvo dealer.2. Ask these folks: https://connectorexperts.com/. 3. You will only find plugs of one gender: the other gender is only available as PCB-mount. Therefore, you will not be able to make a true wire-to-wire extension cord. 4. Don't screw with your car: it's dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Automotive connectors are sometimes custom products designed and made by big names like Molex, Amphenol, TE.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of comments. Apparently TE bought AMP some time ago. I called TE and spend time with one of their techs. They couldn't identify the plug but offered possible alternatives. Unfortunately none will work. If you've never owned a Volvo you may not understand that their parts are made of gold. At least that's how they charge for them. I'm trying to get by on the cheap. And understand the one gender issue.  Connectorexperts.com also couldn't help. I think the keyless header is the way I'll go. Thanks for that. Understand the "working on car" warning. Thanks. Will keep it in mind.